# Remove the N element from a collection

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I need to remove the element in the position "n" from a collection and get that element. 
Is there any method that already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a List, you can do [List.remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29), which returns the element removed.

With a generic Collection, you can't remove an item by index, because not all Collections are ordered by index.

Comment: Andy, I tried that but as I am really new, I dont know why, Eclipse says that remove() expects an object not an integer

Comment: Then your collection is not ordered.  Consider a List intead

Comment: try new ArrayList(collection).remove(i)

Comment: @user1544604 - What is the type of the reference through which you're calling the remove() method?